# Join Three tables (Hibernate annotation exception, OneToMany, mappedBy)

Tags: hibernate, exception, annotations, entity

[image]

I can not **join three tables**. See the picture above. As you can see that every restaurant can have many tables and every table can have many bookings.

Restaurant entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "aadress")
    private String aadress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private List<RestaurantTable> restaurantTables;
}
```

RestaurantTable entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant_table")
public class RestaurantTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private int number;
    @Column(name = "count")
    private int count;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant_table")
    private List<Booking> bookings;
}
```

Booking entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "booking")
public class Booking {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_table_id")
    private RestaurantTable restaurantTable;

    ...
}
```

Hibernate annotation exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Booking.restaurant in RestaurantTable.bookings
```

**Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RestaurantTable

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant_table")
private List<Booking> bookings;
```

you refer to property Booking#***restaurant_table***, but in the Booking entity class this property is named ***restaurantTable***:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_table_id")
private RestaurantTable restaurantTable;
```

Change entity RestaurantTable to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurantTable")
```